# Get the multidimensional array as a result using mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel, multidimensional-array

I have a `campaigns` table which is related `shop` table based on `shop_id`, There are also a `rules` table which is related to `campaigns` table based on `for_camp_id`. I have to fetch the all the data from `campaigns` table based on `shop_id` with all the `rules` created for that specific campaign. I used join query as

```
return DB::table('campaigns')
    ->join('rules', 'campaigns.for_camp_id', '=', 'rules.for_camp_id')
    ->where('campaigns.for_shop_id',$shopId)
    ->get();
```

But it gives me record as a array of collection having each collection with single `rules` with campaign data. I want the result should be returned in proper formatting like a multidimensional array containing array for each campaign, and each campaign array containing created rules for it like

```
array(
    'campaign1'=array(
        'rule1'=>array(),
        'rule2'=array()
    ),
    'campaign2'=array(
        'rule1'=>array(),
        'rule2'=array()
    ),
)
```

Comment: If it returns an array, then there's something wrong; it should return a Collection object

Comment: Just parse the 2d array in PHP, rearranging it to whatever your needs.

Comment: Yeah i can parse, but i am searching a way to mysql returns me in that format

Comment: Dont use raw query, use elaquoant relationship so you will get the result in your desire format.

Comment: If you want Eloquent to return it as you describe, then you'll have to rewrite Eloquent itself, or use your own direct mysqli or pdo queries against the database rather than using the Eloquent interface.... Eloquent is written to retrieve data as a series of collections, and is incredibly easy to work with the results.... why do you need to change this?

Comment: Why not use a [Relation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships) from Campaigns to Rules rather than explicitly JOINing? That would certainly give you something closer to what you're asking for